# What are the dragon die sides in Vast the Crystal Caverns?

Tags: vast-the-crystal-caverns

What are the dragon die sides in Vast the Crystal Caverns and how are they arranged?
I have bought the game but the die is missing(and the figure holders but they are not that important) so I want to make my own die but do not know the side and how they are arranged.

Proof that I am not just trying to make the game without buying it:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the faces for the dragon die in [the public print and play punchboard file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxGSe67fZvvNMklxaHNnYV83S0k) the Vast developers have up.

It also has a useful d6 conversion chart so you can just use a standard d6 instead of trying to make your own die.

[image]

Comment: I know this is technically a link only answer, but it would be extremely hard to provide the useful material from the link in any way other than by just linking to it.

Comment: Thank you so much, I added a picture of the die diagram to the answer so you can approve it if it is ok.